# showModal() in Javascript not working when inside an if statement in a function

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, modal-dialog

I am trying to show a modal after an if statement is true, in my example I am doing this after the user presses Enter, in my real code there are a few other if statements nested into that one.

I wrote [this codepen](https://codepen.io/nbonato/pen/bGQgzap) to illustrate the issue, and I am also putting the code here for clarity.

This is my HTML, pretty basic, creating the dialog and not providing the "open" attribute, so it's hidden by default:

```
Press Enter
<dialog id="greeting">
  <p>Greetings, one and all!<p>
  <form method="dialog">
    <button>&times;</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Then we have the Javascript where I grab the modal and store it in a global variable, create a function listening for pressed keys and another one that parses them. Inside the parsing function, I added the code to (unsuccessfully) show the model only if the pressed key is "ENTER".

```
let greeting = document.getElementById("greeting");
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    parseKey(e.key);
});

function parseKey(pressedKey) {
    pressedKey = pressedKey.toUpperCase()
    if (pressedKey== "ENTER") {
      console.log(greeting);
      greeting.showModal();
      console.log(greeting.getAttribute("open"));
      
      
      //greeting.setAttribute("open", "open");
      
      //alternative = document.getElementById("greeting");
      //console.log(alternative);
      //alternative.showModal();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I also:

1. Used `console.log()` as a sort of debugging tool to make sure the if statement worked and that the modal was actually available inside the function. That seems to work, so when I press Enter, the console shows the HTML code of the modal
2. Logging the value of the "open" attribute for the modal, getting an empty string as a response

In the commented out part I also tried:

1. To set the attribute manually
2. To grab the modal directly inside the function, once again getting the same result of the function logging to the console the HTML of the modal, but the modal remaining hidden

When I tried putting two `showModal()` one after the other, I got the `InvalidStateError: HTMLDialogElement.showModal: Dialog element already has an 'open' attribute`, which makes me think I am clearly missing something, since the modal is still invisible.

Thanks to everybody that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to prevent the native event to be executed.
Add  `e.preventDefault();` and everything should work fine.

Comment: Oh man, I feel so dumb, that indeed fixed it. Thanks a lot! Could I ask you a bit more detail on why that was the case? Why are other commands executed but that one is blocked by the native event?

Comment: I think that pressing enter submit the form inside the dialog. Try without any form inside but i think that i comes from here.